# 4 lines of text vertically aligned, dynamic box width depending on the number of boxes produced in JS

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am loading JSON data (I have commented three different versions) in javascript and then I create boxes depending on the data values. The outcome is a grid as shown below:

```js
var json_data = {"headers":["Platform","Channel","Value","Number1","Comm P1 Number2","Comm P3 Number2","Comm Random1 Number2","Comm Random2 Number2","Comm Total Number2","Comm TW Number2","Comm Random3 Number2","Comm platform6 Number2","Comm platform4 Number2"],"rows":[["platform2","video",19273.28,3300.1060800000005,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513],["platform4","Other",null,18970.479999999992,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513],["platform6","video",49051.31569999999,5380.506584,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513],["platform6","display",2605.0244,null,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513],["platform1","display",19350.6,4642.47,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513],["platform1","video",9460.003,6843.02,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513]]};

//var json_data = {"headers":["Platform","Channel","Value","Number1","Comm P1 Number2","Comm P3 Number2","Comm Random1 Number2","Comm Random2 Number2","Comm Total Number2","Comm TW Number2","Comm Random3 Number2","Comm platform6 Number2","Comm platform4 Number2"],"rows":[["platform2","video",19273.28,3300.1060800000005,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513],["platform4","Other",null,18970.479999999992,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513],["platform1","display",19350.6,4642.47,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513],["platform1","video",9460.003,6843.02,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513]]};

//var json_data = {"headers":["Platform","Channel","Value","Number1","Comm P1 Number2","Comm P3 Number2","Comm Random1 Number2","Comm Random2 Number2","Comm Total Number2","Comm TW Number2","Comm Random3 Number2","Comm platform6 Number2","Comm platform4 Number2"],"rows":[["platform2","video",19273.28,3300.1060800000005,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513],["platform4","Other",null,18970.479999999992,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513],["platform6","video",49051.31569999999,5380.506584,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513],["platform6","display",2605.0244,null,74080,0,0,0,146311,0,19273,52958,45513]]};



    var platform_data = json_data.rows;
    var platform1_element = document.getElementById("platform1");
    var platform2_element = document.getElementById("platform2");
    var platform5_element = document.getElementById("platform5");
    var platform3_element = document.getElementById("platform3");
    var platform6_element = document.getElementById("platform6");
    var platform4_element = document.getElementById("platform4");

    function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
        return self.indexOf(value) === index;
    }
    function formatNumber (num) {
        return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
    }
    var platforms = [];
    for (var i in platform_data) {
        if (platform_data[i][0] != null){
            platforms[i] = platform_data[i][0].toLowerCase();
        }
    }
  
    var unique_platforms = platforms.filter( onlyUnique );

    var target_width = 100/(unique_platforms.length-2);
    var width_str=target_width+"%";

    platform1_element.classList.add("hidden");
    platform2_element.classList.add("hidden");
    platform5_element.classList.add("hidden");
    platform6_element.classList.add("hidden");
    platform3_element.classList.add("hidden");
    platform4_element.classList.add("hidden");
   
    var total_Number1 = 0;
    var total_Number2 = 0;
    var total_display_Number1 = 0;
    var total_video_Number1 = 0;
    var total_mixed_Number1 = 0;
    var total_other_Number1 = 0;
    var total_display_Number2 = 0;
    var total_video_Number2 = 0;
    var total_mixed_Number2 = 0;
    var Number2_numbers = [];
    
    for (var i in unique_platforms) {
        var platform_name = unique_platforms[i].toLowerCase();

        var display_Number1_total = 0;
        var display_Number2_total = 0;
        var video_Number1_total = 0;
        var video_Number2_total = 0;
        var mixed_Number1_total = 0;
        var mixed_Number2_total = 0;
        var other_Number1_total = 0;        
 
        for (var x in platform_data){
            if (platform_data[x][0] != null){
                    if(platform_data[x][0].toLowerCase() == platform_name){
                    switch(platform_data[x][1]) {
                        case "display":
                        // Red Dot
                        display_Number1_total = display_Number1_total + platform_data[x][3];
                        total_Number1 = total_Number1 + display_Number1_total;
                        break;
                        case "video":
                        video_Number1_total = video_Number1_total + platform_data[x][3];
                        total_Number1 = total_Number1 + video_Number1_total;
                        break;
                        case "mixed":
                        mixed_Number1_total = mixed_Number1_total + platform_data[x][3];
                        total_Number1 = total_Number1 + mixed_Number1_total;
                        break;
                        case "Other":
                        other_Number1_total = other_Number1_total + platform_data[x][3];
                        total_Number1 = total_Number1 + other_Number1_total;
                        break;
                        default:
                        doNothing = "";
                    }
                }
            }else {
                Number2_numbers = platform_data[x];
            }            
        }

        var platform_Number1 = display_Number1_total + video_Number1_total + mixed_Number1_total + other_Number1_total;
        var generic_element = document.getElementById(platform_name);

        var element_Number1_name = platform_name+"_Number1";
        var fl_Number1 = parseFloat(platform_Number1).toFixed(0);
        var curr_flag = "&pound;"+formatNumber(fl_Number1);
        document.getElementById(element_Number1_name).innerHTML = curr_flag;

        total_display_Number1 = total_display_Number1 + display_Number1_total;
        total_video_Number1 = total_video_Number1 + video_Number1_total;
        total_mixed_Number1 = total_mixed_Number1 + mixed_Number1_total;
    }

    var total_Number1_string = "<h1>&pound;" + formatNumber(Number(total_Number1).toFixed(0)) + "</h1>";
    //document.getElementById("total_Number1").innerHTML = total_Number1_string;

  if (Number2_numbers.length == 0){
      Number2_numbers = platform_data[0];
  }
  var fl_Number2 = 0;
  var curr_flag_bud = '';
  var element_Number2_name = '';

  
  for (var i in json_data.headers){  
      switch(json_data.headers[i]) {
            case "Comm P1 Number2":
                    element_Number2_name = "platform1_Number2";
                    fl_Number2 = parseFloat(Number2_numbers[i]).toFixed(0);
                    curr_flag_bud = "&pound;"+formatNumber(fl_Number2);
                    document.getElementById(element_Number2_name).innerHTML = curr_flag_bud;
                    break;
           case "Comm Total Number2":
                    element_Number2_name = "total_Number2";
                    fl_Number2 = parseFloat(Number2_numbers[i]).toFixed(0);
                    curr_flag_bud = "<h1>&pound;" +formatNumber(fl_Number2) +"</h1>";
                    //document.getElementById(element_Number2_name).innerHTML = curr_flag_bud;
                    break;
            case "Comm Random3 Number2":
                    element_Number2_name = "platform2_Number2";
                    fl_Number2 = parseFloat(Number2_numbers[i]).toFixed(0);
                    curr_flag_bud = "&pound;" +formatNumber(fl_Number2);
                    document.getElementById(element_Number2_name).innerHTML = curr_flag_bud;
                    break;  
        case "Comm P3 Number2":
                    element_Number2_name = "platform3_Number2";
                    fl_Number2 = parseFloat(Number2_numbers[i]).toFixed(0);
                    curr_flag_bud = "&pound;" +formatNumber(fl_Number2);
                    document.getElementById(element_Number2_name).innerHTML = curr_flag_bud;
                    break; 
           case "Comm TW Number2":
                    element_Number2_name = "platform5_Number2";
                    fl_Number2 = parseFloat(Number2_numbers[i]).toFixed(0);
                    curr_flag_bud = "&pound;" +formatNumber(fl_Number2);
                    document.getElementById(element_Number2_name).innerHTML = curr_flag_bud;
                    break;   
           case "Comm platform6 Number2":
                    element_Number2_name = "platform6_Number2";
                    fl_Number2 = parseFloat(Number2_numbers[i]).toFixed(0);
                    curr_flag_bud = "&pound;" +formatNumber(fl_Number2);
                    document.getElementById(element_Number2_name).innerHTML = curr_flag_bud;
                    break;
           case "Comm platform4 Number2":
                    element_Number2_name = "platform4_Number2";
                    fl_Number2 = parseFloat(Number2_numbers[i]).toFixed(0);
                    curr_flag_bud = "&pound;" +formatNumber(fl_Number2);
                    document.getElementById(element_Number2_name).innerHTML = curr_flag_bud;
                    break;  
                    default:
         } 
    }
    
    var statBox = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.infobox'));

    var element_id;
    
    var parentBoxlist = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.parentbox'));

    var channel_Number1_check = 0;
    var Number1_channels = [];

 //   if (total_mixed_Number1 > 0.0) {channel_Number1_check = channel_Number1_check + 1;Number1_channels[0] = 'mixed';};
 //   if (total_video_Number1 > 0.0) {channel_Number1_check = channel_Number1_check + 1;Number1_channels[1] = 'video';};
 //   if (total_display_Number1 > 0.0) {channel_Number1_check = channel_Number1_check + 1;Number1_channels[2] = 'display';};

    statBox.forEach(function(box) {
        switch(unique_platforms.length) {
            case 1:
                    // 1 box
                    element_id = box.getAttribute('id');
                    if (unique_platforms.includes(element_id)){
                        box.classList.add('infobox1'); 
                        box.classList.remove('hidden');
                    }
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    // 2 box's
                    element_id = box.getAttribute('id');
                    if (unique_platforms.includes(element_id)){
                        box.classList.add('infobox2'); 
                        box.classList.remove('hidden');
                    }
                    break;
                    case 3:
                    // 3 box's
                     element_id = box.getAttribute('id');
                    if (unique_platforms.includes(element_id)){
                        box.classList.add('infobox3'); 
                        box.classList.remove('hidden');
                    }
                    break;  
                    case 4:
                    // 4 box's
                     element_id = box.getAttribute('id');
                    if (unique_platforms.includes(element_id)){
                        box.classList.add('infobox4'); 
                        box.classList.remove('hidden');
                    }
                    break;
                    case 5:
                    // 5 box's
                    element_id = box.getAttribute('id');
                    if (unique_platforms.includes(element_id)){
                        box.classList.add('infobox5'); 
                        box.classList.remove('hidden');
                    } 
                    break;
                    default:
                }
            });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

    body{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Roboto;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    h1{
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    }
    h3{
    font-size: 1.1vw!important;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    }
    .redSq{
    background-color: #ff000a;
    width: 117px;
    height: 241px;
    float:left;
    }
.row {
    display: table;
    width: 99.8%;
    height: 180px; 
    color: #454545;
    background-color:#dee9f3;
    //border: solid 1px #454545; 
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.row > .col-lg-6 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > div {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 20px);
  text-align: left;
}
td{
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 6px 0;
  border: none;
}
table{
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#454545;
  font-weight:500;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing:0.3em 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}
p{
    font-size: 1.2vw;
}
    .boxes{
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 5%;
    min-width: 200px;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    #line{
    border-bottom: solid 1px #CCC;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    }

    .infobox {
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    color: #454545;
    }

    .infobox1 {
    float:left;
    //min-height:150px;
    min-width: 24%;
    margin: 0 0.5%;
    //padding: 18px 0;
    }

    .infobox2 {
    float:left;
    //min-height:150px;
    min-width: 24%;
    margin: 0 0.5%;
    //padding: 18px 0;
    }

    .infobox3 {
    float:left;
    //min-height:150px;
    min-width: 24%;
    margin: 0 0.5%;
    //padding: 18px 0;
    }

    .infobox4 {
    float:left;
    //min-height:150px;
    min-width: 24%;
    margin: 0 0.5%;
    //padding: 18px 0;
    }

    .infobox5 {
    float:left;
    //min-height:150px;
    min-width: 24%;
    margin: 0 0.5%;
    //padding: 18px 0;
    }

    div.leftBox{
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    margin: 15px 0 0 25px;
    font-size: 1.1vw;    
    }
    div.rightBox{
    float:left;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 15px 0 0 25px;
    font-size: 1.1vw;
    }

    .infocontentheader {
    //text-align: center;
    line-height: 2.8;
    //color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    }

    .infocontent{
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    }


    div#platform1.infocontentheader{
    background-color: #3c5999;
    }

    div#platform1.infobox img{
        display: block;
        margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
    }

    p#sTitle {
         font-weight: 900;
         font-size: 1.5vw;
     }

     p#bTitle {
         //font-weight: 900;
         font-size: 1.2vw;
     }

     p#platform1_Number1, p#platform2_Number1, p#platform4_Number1 ,p#platform6_Number1, 
     p#platform3_Number1, p#platform5_Number1 {
         font-weight: 900;
         font-size: 1.3em;
         margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
     }

     p#platform1_Number2, p#platform2_Number2, p#platform4_Number2, p#platform6_Number2,
     p#platform3_Number2, p#platform5_Number2{
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin: 10px 0 0 20px;        
     }

    div#platform5.infocontentheader{
    background-color: #1da1f2;
    }
    div#platform5.infobox img{
        display: block;
        margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
    }

.infobox img{
       max-width:30px;
    }

    div#platform6.infocontentheader{
    background-color: #a15aa0;
    }

    div#display.parentbox{
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
    color: #fff;
    }

    div#video.parentbox{
    background-color: #999999;
    color: #fff;
    }

    div#mixed.parentbox{
    background-color: #c1c1c1;
    color: #fff;
    }

    #platform6 div.infocontentheader{
    color: #fff;
    }
    div#platform6.infobox img{

        display: block;
        margin: 15% auto 0 auto;
    }

    div#platform6_value.infocontent{
    color: #000;
    }

    div#platform2.infocontentheader{
    background-color: #ff0102;
    }
    div#platform2.infobox img{
    display: block;
    margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
    }
    div#platform4.infocontentheader{
        background-color: #cac9c2;
    }
    div#platform4.infobox img{
        display: block;
        margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
    }
  div#platform3.infobox{
    background-color: #bb95a9;
    }
    div#platform3.infobox img{
    display: block;
    margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
    }

    .hidden{
    display:none;
    }
    
    #parent_div_1{
        width:50%;
        min-height: 150px;
        background-color: #757476;
        margin-right:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    #parent_div_2{
        width:50%;
        min-height: 150px;
        background-color: #8D8D8D;
        margin-right:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    .parentbox{
        width:33.33%;
        min-height: 150px;
        /*background-color: #8D8D8D;*/
        margin-right:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    .parentbox1{
        width:100%;
        min-height: 150px;
        margin-right:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    .parentbox2{
        width:50%;
        min-height: 150px;
        margin-right:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    .parentbox3{
        width:33.33%;
        min-height: 150px;
        margin-right:0px;
        float:left;
    }
    .child_div_1{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    }
    .child_div_2{
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    }
     .child_Number2{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding-left:15%;
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    }
    .child_Number1{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    padding-right: 15%;
    text-align: left;
    float:right;
    }
     .child_title{
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    }
    .child_Number2_number{
        padding-right: 20%;
    }
    .child_Number1_number{
        padding-left: 20%;
    }

.boxbox {
    float:left;
    display: table;
    width: 99.8%;
    height: 180px; 
    color: #454545;
    font-size:1.1vw;
}
.boxbox > .col-lg-6 {
    min-width: 50px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper2" style="height:160px;">
<div class="infobox" id="platform1">
<div class="boxbox">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #3c5999; ">
    <img src="https://downloads.andyroid.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/mr-square-icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">Number1<br>
        <div id="platform1_Number1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">Number2<br>
        <div id="platform1_Number2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="infobox" id="platform5">
<div class="boxbox">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #3c5999; ">
    <img src="https://downloads.andyroid.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/mr-square-icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">Number1<br>
        <div id="platform5_Number1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">Number2<br>
        <div id="platform5_Number2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="infobox" id="platform6">
<div class="boxbox">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #a15aa0; ">
    <img src="https://downloads.andyroid.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/mr-square-icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">Number1<br>
        <div id="platform6_Number1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">Number2<br>
        <div id="platform6_Number2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="infobox" id="platform2">
<div class="boxbox">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #ff0102; ">
    <img src="https://downloads.andyroid.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/mr-square-icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">Number1<br>
        <div id="platform2_Number1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">Number2<br>
        <div id="platform2_Number2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="infobox" id="platform4">
<div class="boxbox">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #cac9c2; ">
    <img src="https://downloads.andyroid.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/mr-square-icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">Number1<br>
        <div id="platform4_Number1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">Number2<br>
        <div id="platform4_Number2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="infobox" id="platform3">
<div class="boxbox">
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="background-color: #3c5999; ">
    <img src="https://downloads.andyroid.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/mr-square-icon.png">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6" style="float: left;">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="sTitle">Number1<br>
        <div id="platform3_Number1"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="bTitle">Number2<br>
        <div id="platform3_Number2"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
</body>
```

Ideally, **I would like to make the text align to the center.** There are two lines (each one has a `<br>`) and I would like them to have exactly the same margin (dynamically) from the top and bottom (and between them).

**The second thing** I want to achieve is described below:

If I comment the current JSON in the javascript and use the second one, the grid does not look good. Considering that I have less than 4 boxes, the width of each box should not be 25%. Of course, there is no dynamic way to do this in the CSS. I can change the way javascript works and create different `infoboxes` and then add more lines in the CSS but I do not think this is the best approach.

Do you think I should just build the box with the floated image on the left and the two lines of text on the side - vertically aligned - and then add the code in a more responsive gridbox/flexbox? Or is it easier to just edit the current one? Ideally, depending on the number of boxes, I should be getting something like the following:

4 boxes:
[image]

3 boxes:
[image]

In case of 5 boxes, the image above will apply and 2 additional boxes will be added underneath. The two boxes will be horizontally aligned with the same spaces between them.

Comment: Have you try CSS flex? [see this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Did you even look at his code?

Comment: @ShaileshRathod OP is already using flexbox layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the first part of your issue, however it is unclear what the second part of your question is as it's a wall of text with little clarity. I would suggest asking one question at a time and simplifying out the issue into a simple example.

---

To get the text to center correctly I would use just Flexbox and remove all other display types such as display table. Keeping it simple you could have something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="boxbox">
      <div class="image-wrap" style="background-color: #3c5999; ">
        <img src="https://downloads.andyroid.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/mr-square-icon.png">
      </div>
      <div class="content-wrap" style="float: left;">
        <div class="container">
          <div id="sTitle">Number1
            <br>
            <div id="platform1_Number1"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="bTitle">Number2
            <br>
            <div id="platform1_Number2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 75px;
}

.content-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.content-wrap .container {
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content-wrap .container div {
  flex: inherit;
}
```

Using a flex property such as space-around will give you centered and well spaced content.

**Check out this fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/sz4rw4yf/

**More info on flexbox**
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

**A bootstrap type grid with flexbox:**
http://flexboxgrid.com/

---

Also, at a guess based off of your selectors I would say you are using some CSS framework such as bootstrap and have gone on to apply the grid classes incorrectly. For example you have used the column markup col-lg-6 but this is then overwritten and invalidated. I would take out all of the grid classes and keep this simple to start with.